# Any way for me get the nice 'as you type' autocomplete suggestions in my People and Groups fields?

Tags: column, 2016, clientpeoplepicker

Using SharePoint 2016 On Premises, vanilla set up and I’m a noob.

In various places where SharePoint shows People & Groups entry, it offers a nice PeoplePicker interface where as you type a name, you are shown matches as you type, to pick from. Examples being in Task Lists where you assign a person.

However, if I add a Person column to a bespoke list, I get a nasty clunky user experience with a text input box and a directory button. With this interface, the user either has to click the directory and search, or type a name and then get the system to correct it as an exact match.

Is there anyway to get my lists to exhibit the 'nice' behaviour and make my users happy?

Answer (score 0):

You might wana check on this link buddy
http://spjsblog.com/2010/03/25/autocomplete-for-sharepoint-people-picker/

Comment: Many thanks. From the comments it looks as if the solution was created for 2007 and needed to be updated to work on  2010, so I doubt it is suitable for 2016. Also I’m afraid I need the ability to add multiple names, which this doesn’t support.  However, knowing that it is called the 'PeoplePicker' seems to open up a world of Googleable possibilities.